# vulnerable ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar

Tags: apache-poi

I get a warning from jenkins check vulnerability:

File Path C:\jenkins\workspace\Check vulnerability\myApp.war\WEB-INF\lib\ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar

SHA-1 147993bd2ef26de9e54728f6762011c8c6b8cda7

SHA-256 f8256738040d66ccb677814873674c1212464e00af491e9df490fc45decbd932

Description Apache POI in versions prior to release 3.17 are vulnerable to Denial of Service Attacks: 1) Infinite Loops while parsing crafted WMF, EMF, MSG and macros (POI bugs 61338 and 61294), and 2) Out of Memory Exceptions while parsing crafted DOC, PPT and XLS (POI bugs 52372 and 61295).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

There are two CVE warnings: CVE-2017-12626, CVE-2017-5644
but both about Apache POI in versions prior to release 3.15 and 3.17 respectively

is there really a vulnerability in ooxml-schemas-1.4.jar? and is there any other way to remove duplicate styles from excel files without using this library?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the reporting tool - the problems identified are on the `poi` and `poi-ooxml` jars not the `ooxml-schemas` one

Comment: the fact is that poi is using ooxml-schemas, because of what the error may look like this

Comment: Apache POI requires either `ooxml-schemas` or `poi-ooxml-schemas`. However, neither of those were affected by the bugs mentioned. So, your reporting tool is broken....